# Using Google App script library in Google spreadsheet add-on

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, shared-libraries, add-on

I have a Google Spread sheet add-on, Formula Tracer Sidebar. I also have App Script library, I want to use some of its functionality within the add-on server code. Library is deployed and shared to anyone with link

[image]

addon loads the library with the following self executing function:

```
const _ftUtils = (function(){
   return FTCommon.getUtils();
})();
```

*where:*

`FTCommon` is the library identifier in the `appscript.json` as the below partial `appscript.json` shows.

```
"dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "FTCommon",
        "libraryId": "1APwfEOzs5n55tSXp2xvrQRqd_YK4pUInssQQH3epxnQWp4DVQ5gmWhlR",
        "version": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
```

However, when launching the add-on all users but me (library owner), fail with the following library missing error message.

[image]

Why is it happening and how to fix?

Comment: *Portuguese* and *Japanese* aside, does this happen on any project you attempt to link or just this one? Does it work if it is set to edit instead of view? What are your publication settings of the add-on?

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou 1) I have one other project uses this library. This one is owned by me 2) I didn't check edit permission, and I can not really check that unless going live, as the addon is available only in via marketplace. I think because I have no organization, I can not define test user ( I am not sure though, I didn't figure out this issue yet. If  necessary I will test it live for one minute, but I prefer not to. 3) What do you mean by _publication settings_?  4) If I understand correctly, do Portuguese and Japanese need special treatment?